# preg_replace_callback returning an empty string?

Tags: php

I have a WordPress plugin which (for part of its features), can run php inside a post and put the output in the proper place on the screen. The Code looks like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'twomb_autocode_do_php', 0); //Parse php in the post with [php] ... [/php] tags.
function twomb_autocode_do_php($content) {
    $content = preg_replace_callback('/\[php\]((.|\n)+)\[\/php\]/', 'twomb_autocode_exec_php', $content); //I know, weird regex.
    return $content;
}

function twomb_autocode_exec_php($matches) {
    ob_start();
    eval($matches[1]);
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

However, when something simple like `[php]echo "hi!";[/php]` is in a post, the content returned is "" (empty). If no php tags are included, the content shows up fine (though obviously with no php in it). I've looked all over the place for `preg_replace_callback` returning an empty string, and the only thing remotely close I've found is a bogus bug on php that invalid unicode characters causes `preg_replace_callback` to return an empty string, though I'm almost certain my string does not have any unicode characters at all.

-Michael.

P.S. Sorry about the formatting -- my screen reader does not work well at all with the editor on this site.

Comment: tried to `var_dump` your `$matches` yet? i bet something to do with those `ob_*`

Comment: Probably the nested match. You don't need it it. Do `/\[php\]([^\]]+)\[\/php\]/`.  That said, if I'm understanding you correctly this code is a giant security hole. There's almost never a reason to use `eval()`